# Multiprocess headless OpenGL processing on EC2 GPU instances

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, glut, glx

My core problem is that I need to run multiple OpenGL executables concurrently on an EC2 GPU instance; I'm observing non-deterministic segfaults when trying to do this.  The same program runs fine (with concurrency) on my Macbook Pro.

The application works as follows:

- python script launches multiple worker executables (i.e. concurrent `subprocess.call()` calls from a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` threadpool).  The python script provides a JSON file as worker input and the worker writes JSON to a file.
- Each worker is a C++ program that does some headless image rendering in OpenGL using fragment shaders and a render-to-texture pipeline.  I've tried using both Glut and GLX rendering contexts.

I'm confident that neither the python script nor the C++ workers have major bugs because the whole application runs fine when:

- running a single worker on the EC2 GPU instance
- running one or more workers on my Macbook (OSX 10.7.4)

The specific error I observe is that one or more of the workers will segfault inside an OpenGL call (e.g. `glTexSubImage2D`, `glDrawElements`, etc) after a few minutes of execution.  Sometimes I've seen failures in the GLX context setup stage (e.g. `glXCreateNewContext` or `glXChooseFBConfig`).  If I start more workers (i.e. higher concurrency), I see errors sooner.  If I start fewer workers, it can take 15-30 minutes before a crash.

I believe that I'm having some sort of OpenGL context or driver issue.  I've tried setting up my context using both GLUT and GLX and neither seems to help.

My procedure for creating the EC2 instance is very close to the instructions given here: http://hpc.nomad-labs.com/archives/139 .  The specific packages I install are:

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libegl1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra llvm-dev imagemagick libboost-all-dev python2.6 python-imaging python-matplotlib python-numpy python-scipy firefox clang python-setuptools python-scipy libatlas-dev ccache libpng12-dev libmagick++-dev glew-utils xvfb x11-utils qiv xinit`

On both OSX and Linux, the C++ worker links: `GL GLU glut pthread m X11`.

I generated my xorg.conf using:

`$ nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=None --virtual=1280x1024`

Before running my program, I run:

`$ startx &; export DISPLAY=:0`

I've tried some non-nvidia drivers, but they don't seem to help either.

I've also consulted the FAQ on parallel processing with OpenGL: http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html
The guide suggests that multithreaded GLX on Ubuntu doesn't work (and I've confirmed that personally.. :) but it seems that multiprocess GLX should be feasible and stable.

Does anybody have any ideas as to

- why the OpenGL/GLX calls might be failing? Am I indeed seeing a driver issue?  It seems like Mac GPU drivers have some sort of 'magic feature' aiding concurrent OpenGL usage.  Are there any Ubuntu/Linux drivers with that same feature?
- are there best practices for running multiple OpenGL executables concurrently on an EC2 GPU instance (or any headless Ubuntu/Linux machine for that matter)?  Can anybody point me towards Open Source software that does this?

Answer (score 0):

.. 1 year later..

I've found that a lot of times the gpu won't be enable on headless machines.
try to vnc in first and see if that helps.